# jQuery UI Sortable - IE6 & IE7 z-index issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use jQuery UI's sortable but when dragging from one container to another, the item is appearing BEHIND the container.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7LrLE/8/

I've uploaded a screen:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="droppable grid-9">
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>ccccccccccccccc</li>
</ul>
<ul class="droppable grid-9">
  <li>xxxxxxxxxxx</li>
  <li>yyyyyyyyyyyy</li>
  <li>zzzzzzzzzzzzzz</li>
</ul>
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
$('.droppable').sortable({
  appendTo: 'body'
  axis: 'y',
  connectWith: '.droppable',
  zIndex: 5
}).disableSelection();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

### FIXED

I was able to fix the issue using the following jQuery code:

```
$('.droppable').sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  connectWith: '.droppable',
  over: function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', '1');
  },
  start: function() {
    $(this).css('z-index','2');
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: A [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) test case showing the problem would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to dynamically decrement the `zIndex` property so that the element above has a higher `zIndex` than the one below

Comment: hoping there is a better way.

Comment: dtan: how would you go about doing that?

Comment: you would get the number (effectively becoming the length) of elements you have to affect, loop through that many number of times and then decrement from a set `zIndex`